# How to compare two elements in same list in jenkins?

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I was running a jenkins declarative pipeline job where I was trying to compare elements of a list and fetch only the same part of two elements.

Example:

```
myList = [/lambda/billMechanism/createCustomerOrderBill, /lambda/billMechanism/createCustomerOrderBill/src, /lambda/billMechanism/createCustomerOrderBill/test, /lambda/billMechanism/isLastPaidBillInCracePeriod, /lambda/billMechanism/isLastPaidBillInCracePeriod/src, /lambda/billMechanism/isLastPaidBillInCracePeriod/test,/lambda/copyPaymentInfo, /lambda/copyPaymentInfo/src, /lambda/copyPaymentInfo/test, /lambda/custOrdWorkflFinancialCharge, /lambda/custOrdWorkflFinancialCharge/src, /lambda/custOrdWorkflFinancialCharge/test,]
```

My expected output:

```
myList = [/lambda/billMechanism/createCustomerOrderBill,/lambda/billMechanism/isLastPaidBillInCracePeriod, /lambda/copyPaymentInfo, /lambda/custOrdWorkflFinancialCharge,]
```

Here, I am only trying to fetch the common parts by comparing 2 elements from same list.

I was trying to iterate through for loop but it was taking more time.

```
`for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
                    s1 = "${myList[i]}"
                    for (int j = i+1; j < myList.size(); j++) {

                            sh "echo ${myList[j]}"

                    }
                }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `groupBy` and remove the variable parts like `/src` and `/test`:

```
def myList = ['/lambda/billMechanism/createCustomerOrderBill', '/lambda/billMechanism/createCustomerOrderBill/src', '/lambda/billMechanism/createCustomerOrderBill/test', '/lambda/billMechanism/isLastPaidBillInCracePeriod', '/lambda/billMechanism/isLastPaidBillInCracePeriod/src', '/lambda/billMechanism/isLastPaidBillInCracePeriod/test', '/lambda/copyPaymentInfo', '/lambda/copyPaymentInfo/src', '/lambda/copyPaymentInfo/test', '/lambda/custOrdWorkflFinancialCharge', '/lambda/custOrdWorkflFinancialCharge/src', '/lambda/custOrdWorkflFinancialCharge/test',]

def commonParts = myList.groupBy{ it.replaceFirst( /\/(src|test)$/, '' ) }.keySet()

assert commonParts.toString() == '[/lambda/billMechanism/createCustomerOrderBill, /lambda/billMechanism/isLastPaidBillInCracePeriod, /lambda/copyPaymentInfo, /lambda/custOrdWorkflFinancialCharge]'
```

Comment: What does the 3rd line do here ?


assert commonParts.toString() == '[/lambda/billMechanism/createCustomerOrderBill, /lambda/billMechanism/isLastPaidBillInCracePeriod, /lambda/copyPaymentInfo, /lambda/custOrdWorkflFinancialCharge]'

Comment: it's an assert to prove that the code does what it supposed to do. Using println or alike is stupid for this purpose